# Pin all elements to top of div using JS, but keep horizontal position

Tags: jquery, css

I have a series of square `<li>` elements inside a fixed width `ul`.  As they reach the edge of the `<ul>`, they drop onto a new row, so there are 3 rows of `<li>`s (imagine a brick wall made up of `<li>` elements).

I need to pin all of these to the top edge of the `<ul>`, so there's only one row, with all of them layered on top.  The problem is that if I use `position: absolute; top:0;`, the horizontal position is lost.

Is there any way of doing this with javascript so that the horizontal position is retained, but they are pinned to the top of the `<ul>`?  It doesn't matter that they'll all overlap and stack on top of each other

Comment: What are the `display` and `position` css values set to for the `ul` and `li` elements?

Comment: `ul` is `display:block; position:relative`, `li` are all left to the natural document flow at the moment: `display:block; width:40px; height:40px; float:left;`

Comment: I also highly doubt this can be done with CSS, without setting an absolute `left:40px` on each `li`, then repeating for each `li` and incrementing that value.  Was hoping for a quick JS fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to let them layout naturally and then change their style to `position:absolute`, `top:0` and `left:(insert the value of each element's offsetLeft)`.

**edit: example**

```
var container = document.getElementById('hover-days');
var elements = container.getElementsByTagName('li');
var lefts = [];

// first read the values
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
    lefts[i] = elements[i].offsetLeft;
}

// then set them
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
    var el = elements[i];
    el.style.left = lefts[i] + 'px';
    el.style.top = '0px';
    el.style.position = 'absolute';
}
```

Comment: Is there no way of doing this without manually setting the left position?  Hence the use of JS?

Comment: I meant you change it from JS but wasn't clear, sorry. Please see the edit.

Comment: And this only works after the elements have been able to layout. If you don't want them to show before they're all pinned, maybe make the container invisible.

Comment: Of course, if their width is fixed, then you don't need them to layout, you can use calculated values instead of the offsetLeft.

Comment: That looks promising, thanks, but my JS is pretty limited - the `li`s are `#hover-days ul li` - how can I drop that into the code example there?

Comment: Thanks etonio - I tweaked that a bit and it's working nicely now!

Answer (score 1):

If you can use CSS3 selectors, `:nth-child()` pseudo selector can help you (you have a fixed width list, so I assumed you will always have the same number of `li`s in a row).

```
ul { width: 150px; height: 150px; position: relative; }

li { width: 50px; height: 50px; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }

li:nth-child(3n-1) { left: 50px; }

li:nth-child(3n) { left: 100px; }
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wyRQF/)

In case you need a jQuery solution, I wrote this little neat function:

```
$('li').css('left', function (index) {
    var $me=$(this),
        myWidth=$me.width(),
        myLeft=(index % 3)*myWidth;
    return myLeft;
});
```

This code assumes that `li` are already set to `position: absolute; top: 0;` and the `ul` to `position: relative` and all widths and heights are set using CSS.

[2nd jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wyRQF/2/)

Reading your comments, just use `#hover-days ul li` instead of `li` as the jQuery selector.